# Extra Tax added to order created via WooCommerce Rest Api

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am having issues with order total where order is created using woo api (/wp-json/wc/v3/orders). My tax setting says "Yes, I will enter prices inclusive of tax". But when an order is created via api, tax is added on top of total amount passed for line item. Please note I don't have any issue with tax where order is directly created on my website. I am not sure why tax is applied on line items total ?? Anyone please help. Also, please note that I am unable to make any change in the request message as it originates from an external marketplace .. I need to know what is know if any .. and how to fix it .. is there a filter/hook i can use to avoid this happening with orders created via api

Sample request:

[image: Sample request]

Order created in woocommerce:

[image: Order created in woocommerce]

woocommerce tax settings:

[image: woocommerce tax settings]

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is the `total`-field in your request. As soon as you provide a total the tax calculation will fail as in your example.

So just remove `total` from your sample request and everything will work!